# Android positioning in linear layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview

I have a listview with each entry being populated with 3 textviews and 1 checkbox. I want the textviews to be underneath one another (as they are), but I want the checkbox to appear over to the right and not underneath which I can't seem to get working.

Here is my xml code for each item in the listview,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <TextView android:id="@+id/name"
  android:textSize="14sp" 
  android:textStyle="bold" 
  android:textColor="#000080" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
<TextView android:id="@+id/cityState" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/phone" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


       <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkbox_bought"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/bought"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

You can see that the TextView name is in it's own horizontal linear layout because i was trying to put the checkbox in there and making it appear at the right, but this just doesn't work at all. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a LinearLayout with orientation vertical which contains the TextViews, and the checkBox on the right of this LinearLayout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="test1"
        android:textColor="#000080"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cityState"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="test2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="test3" />


</LinearLayout>

 <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox_bought"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/bought" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use AbsoluteLayout for this.

```
     <AbsoluteLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

     <Paste your all  3 textviews and 1 checkbox >

     </AbsoluteLayout>
```

If you use absolute layout, you can arrange easily with x y coordinates.

Comment: **AbsoluteLayout** is deprecated.

Comment: Never use an absolute layout. With such a wide range of devices you may be able to get everything looking right on one device, but it won't be that way on others. There is a good reason it is deprecated.